# Can i share the same App id and App Secret between an iOS App and the corresponding Facebook Game?

Tags: ios, facebook-login, app-id, app-secret

I have seen this new policy and I'm a bit worried:

> *(Games on Facebook.com and mobile must not share the same app ID with desktop web games off of Facebook.com)

I have 3 apps that shared the same app id and app secret: a website that use facebook login, the corresponding facebook app and the corresponding ios app that use the fb connect.

Now i ve changed the app id  and app secret of the website, that's clear.

I m not sure if i have to change also the app id and app secret of ios app or if i can continue to share it between fb app and ios app.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can keep use the same appid for your ios and facebook.com app. 
The point is not to share appid with the facebook connected applications